# run sql for other tables if one does not exists (ignore missing tables do not fail)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have many tables in bigquery. I need to create a table which has name of people in each table who is older than 20.
I created something like this but this one fails if one of the tables does not exist.
(I am running it for different projects and their tables are slightly different for example one of the projects does not have tableA)

```
WITH
a As (
    SELECT name
    FROM 'tableA'
    WHERE age >20
),
b As (
    SELECT name
    FROM 'tableB'
    WHERE age >20
)

SELECT name FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM b
```

How can I prevent the failure and say if the table exist then find people older than 20 otherwise ignore it and run for other tables?
(This is an Airflow task which fails)

Comment: Tables need to exist to reference them.  I think you are stuck with constructing the query dynamically if you don't know if the tables exist.

Comment: @GordonLinoff would you please explain more about constructing the query dynamically?

Comment: What he mean is - you need to create some sort of stored procedure to check if table exist first and then construct the query accordingly. This is the dynamically written query he is talking about.

Comment: Could you explain more about your process? I see you are trying to query two tables, you also mentioned it is used within Airflow and lastly that you are using the same task for other project. Did I get it right? I need more details to properly address this question.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Hi Alex, that is right. I have an airflow task which run the above query with 20 tables. I need to run the code for 3 different project on bigquery and their tables are slightly different. For example I have 3 projects on bigquery called school1, school2, school3. each project has a dataset called classes. It has tables called tableA, TableB,... but school2 does not have tableA or school3 does not have tableB. So my query fails although it works for dataset with all required table(e.g. school1).

Comment: @GordonLinoff If the query is running in BigQuery, there is the option of wildcard tables, which lets you query a "dynamic" list of tables. Check my answer for details. Note that this only applies for BigQuery. AFAIK, wildcard tables is not a feature of regular SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

A BigQuery-only solution would be to use wildcard tables.

There are several options here:

- If all the tables in the dataset are being queried:

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM `project.dataset.*`
WHERE age > 20
```

- If all the table names in all the datasets are known:

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM `project.dataset.*`
WHERE age > 20
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX IN ('tableA', 'tableB', ..., 'tableN')
```

- If all the tables in all the datasets conform to a specific pattern:

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM `project.dataset.*`
WHERE age > 20
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE 'table%'
```

The [`LIKE` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators) (combined with [logical operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#logical_operators)) on the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` field give a lot of freedom to match a lot of patterns for table names without the need to explicitly list all the table names, as it is needed for the [`IN` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#in_operators). If no table matches the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` specified (i.e. it is not listed in the array of the `IN` operator), the query will return 0 results instead of failing.

More details about querying wildcard tables in the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables).

Note that non-matching schemas could cause some issues, so you might want to include a verification that the matched tables have the right schema with a query to the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view):

```sql
WITH correct_schema_tables as (SELECT table_name FROM (
  SELECT * FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      column_name = 'name'
      AND data_type = 'STRING')
  JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      column_name = 'age'
      AND data_type = 'INT64')
  USING (table_name)
)


SELECT name 
FROM `project.dataset.*`
WHERE age > 20
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (SELECT table_name FROM correct_schema_tables)
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE 'table%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have one composer environment and want it to use the [BigQueryOperator()](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator) to query data in 3 different projects.

I am assumig you have already created your Composer environment in your project. Then, you can follow the below steps:

**1)** Create 3 different connections between your Composer environment and each project you will query against. Such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_a_connection_to_another_project).

**2)** Create a specific query for each project, where you filter `age>20` and append all the tables together. So, you will address properly the tables for each project.

**3)** [Create one DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#dag-assignment) file with 3 BigQueryOperators, each referencing a particular connection and using the appropriate query, created in **2**. The DAG creation is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags) and the DAG would be as follows:

```
task_custom = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='task_custom_connection_school1',
    bql_1='SELECT * WHERE age>20', use_legacy_sql=False,
    # Set a connection ID to use a connection that you have created in step 1.
    bigquery_conn_id='my_gcp_connection')
```

*As an alternative you can create multiple DAG files, one for each connection. In addition, notice that the connection name is specified with `bigquery_conn_id`.*

Following the above steps, each of your queries would be tailored specifically for each project. Thus, they would be executed properly.

Comment: @Saba, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer in case you found the information useful.